# Isotropy of 5-dimensional quadratic forms

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

There is an exercise in Ch X of TY Lam's book Introduction to quadratic forms which asks us to prove that if a 5-dimensional quadratic form is universal then it is isotropic.

I have been able to prove an easier version of it which shows if a 3-dimensional quadratic form is universal then it is isotropic.

I approached it in the following way: Let $\sigma$ be a 5-dim form with d($\sigma$)=d. Since
$\sigma$ is universal , it represents d . Hence $\sigma$ $\cong$ $<d>$ $\bot$ $\gamma$  where $\gamma$ is 4- dim form with d($\gamma$)=1. Hence, $\gamma$ is a Pfister neighbor and a.$\gamma$ $\subseteq$ $\tau$ where $\tau$ is 2-fold Pfister form.

I am stuck here and don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: It's in Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms. Pigeonholes, as I recall. Alright, Lemma 2.7 on page 60. Uses Corollary same page, a regular ternary represents all except possibly one squareclass; these are the p-adic fields which Lam does not

Comment: Isn't the corollary only for for fields Qp? The question is for arbitrary fields.

Comment: Right. I'm comparing in Lam (2005) Your ternary thing is problem 6 on page 75. I suspect you can tweak Cassels just a little

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted solution is the correct way to start.  Let's now finish your solution using the notation you have already introduced. We have
$a \sigma = <ad> \perp a \gamma = <ad> \perp \tau$, where $\tau$ is a $2$-fold
Pfister form.
Let $\psi = <1, ad> \otimes \tau$, which is a $3$-fold Pfister form.
Since $a\sigma$ is also universal and is a proper subform of $\psi$, it follows that $\psi$ is isotropic.  Since $\psi$ is a Pfister form, it follows that
$\psi$ is hyperbolic.
Any $5$-dimensional subform of $\psi$, such as $a\sigma$, must be isotropic.
Therefore, $\sigma$ is isotropic.